# Pandas groupby transform max solution?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

**Context:**

My dataframe columns are: ID's (with duplicates) in `A`, time values `B`, and string values `C`

I need to update all `C` values where `C` corresponds to the most recent time `B` for each ID `A`.

Shows the latest time for ID (or group of IDs), but doesn't include C values:

```
df.groupby(['A'], as_index=False)['B'].max()
```

My failed attempt after stumbling onto `.transform()`:

```
df['C'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(['C'].max())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'max'
```

**Data**

```
'a':['zx5','zx5','ab1','ab1','mn3','mn3'],
'b':['1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021','1/4/2021'],
'c':['aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff']
```

**Desired result:**

```
'a':['zx5','zx5','ab1','ab1','mn3','mn3'],
'b':['1/1/2021','1/2/2021','1/3/2021','1/4/2021','1/5/2021','1/4/2021'],
'c':['bbb','bbb','ddd','ddd','eee','eee']
```

If applicable, I am looking for an efficient solution as this consists of csv's with 100,000+ rows of data.

**Edit:**
Due to comments, I've updated IDs (A) to be less simplistic, consider them as random alphanumeric values where sorting doesn't provide benefit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can convert `b` [`to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) if not already (for correct sort behaviour), then [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) so that the maximal `b` value is last, then [`groupby transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.transform.html) last and let index alignment associate the values correctly:

```
# df['b'] = pd.to_datetime(df['b'])  # Convert to_datetime if not already

df['c'] = df.sort_values('b').groupby('a')['c'].transform('last')
```

`df`:

```
     a          b    c
0  zx5 2021-01-01  bbb
1  zx5 2021-01-02  bbb
2  ab1 2021-01-03  ddd
3  ab1 2021-01-04  ddd
4  mn3 2021-01-05  eee
5  mn3 2021-01-04  eee
```

---

Some timing via `%timeit`:

```
%timeit df.sort_values('b').groupby('a')['c'].transform('last')
275 µs ± 6.23 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df['a'].map(df.sort_values(by='b').groupby('a')['c'].last())
322 µs ± 8.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: It is quite normal that transform is faster, it has to go through the rows only once ;) Just thought of it after you posted

Comment: @HenryEcker ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: I don't get that with the provided sample data. Can you provide a sample that does?

Comment: @HenryEcker df.reset_index(inplace=True) fixed my issue, tyvm

Answer (score 1):

You can sort by 'a'+'b', keep the most recent 'b' per 'a' group and use this to map your new column 'c' data:

```
keys = df.sort_values(by='b').groupby('a')['c'].last()
df['c'] = df['a'].map(keys)
```

output:

```
    a          b    c
0  A1 2021-01-01  bbb
1  A1 2021-01-02  bbb
2  A2 2021-01-03  ddd
3  A2 2021-01-04  ddd
4  A3 2021-01-05  eee
5  A3 2021-01-04  eee
```

Comment: Thanks @HenryEcker, I just noticed ;)

Comment: @mozway I've updated the IDs, consider them random alphanumeric values - sorting does not benefit us here

Comment: Well, you can only sort by 'b'